# Lumen realtime API

Tags: laravel, api, lumen

I have created a restfulAPI with Lumen.
Everything is working. GET POST PUT DELETE

Now, I want to make it realtime..
I am calling this API in other project and using GET and POST.
What I want is, when POST is used. The content stored via add should be updated wherever GET is used.

How should I go with it?
I have no idea.

If the question is inapt or should not be asked here, please tell me where should I ask then.

Thankyou for help

Answer (score 1):

Providing you are storing data in some kind of database when you make your `POST` requests, your client will need to make a `GET` request to refresh the data.

You can't make the data magically update in the client without making another `GET` request unless you choose to use web-sockets instead of HTTP requests.

Comment: i see.. In Laravel we do everything separately, like use pusher or redis and queue. Is it same way in Lumen or something better is available?

Comment: Yes you can do that in Lumen, but that doesn't sound like what you were asking. You can still process queues using Lumen and Redis (or any other supported provider). With Pusher, that implementation makes use of web-sockets as I outlined in the answer.